# Base 64 Conversion Resulting in Incorrect Result with Java Base64 Library

Tags: java, base64

My goal was to take a string, (in this case a password) find it's MD5 Hash, and convert it to base64. This is the first part of the encryption that is made by a browser that I am trying to automate logging on to. When I test the password "test", it goes through fine. However, when trying "asdf", I am getting different hash values. I know that it is the problem of the base64 conversion part, because the MD5 hashes are always correct. You can see the "correct" output by finding the MD5 hash of "asdf" (912ec803b2ce49e4a541068d495ab570) and pasting that into the HEX box [here.](http://tomeko.net/online_tools/hex_to_base64.php?lang=en)

A link for the code below with the "test" password- https://ideone.com/SmaNsR
A link for the code below with the "asdf" password- /OOSrmV (can only post 2 links)

```
class myClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String password = "asdf";
        try {
            System.out.println(password);
            password = (passwordencrypt(password));
            System.out.println(password);

        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException ex) {
             System.out.println("oops");
        }
        password = base16to64(password);

        System.out.println(password);

    }

    public static String passwordencrypt(String password) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        md.update(password.getBytes());
        byte[] b = md.digest();
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        for (byte b1 : b) {
            sb.append(Integer.toHexString(b1 & 0xff).toString());
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
    public static String base16to64(String hex){
    return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(new BigInteger(hex, 16).toByteArray());
    }

}
```

EDIT: Per jrtapsell's recommendation, sample inputs and outputs.

Input: "test"
My program:        CY9rzUYh03PK3k6DJie09g==
What it should be: CY9rzUYh03PK3k6DJie09g==

Input: "asdf"
My program:        AJEuyDss5J5KVBaNSVq1cA==
What it should be: kS7IA7LOSeSlQQaNSVq1cA==

Comment: Could you add your expected inputs and outputs to the question, so they can be compared against more easily please

Comment: Why hex encode to then base64 encode?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch MD5 is already base64 encoded, so I wanted to decode it, and encode it in base64. If you are asking why this whole process, it is because I am trying to build an app that can automatically log in to [this site](https://pschool.aaps.k12.mi.us/public/), and that is the way that that site transmits credentials.

The process I am trying to do it hex_md5>base64_md5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't convert to hex to then decode the hex and encode to base64, simplify your code - encode to base64 directly. Something like,

```
public static String passwordencrypt(String password) 
        throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
    md.update(password.getBytes());
    byte[] b = md.digest();
    return base64(b);
}

public static String base64(byte[] bytes) {
    return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(bytes);
}
```

And then remove the call to `base16to64` in `main` and I get

```
kS7IA7LOSeSlQQaNSVq1cA==
```

Which matches the base64 String on your linked website.

Comment: Wow. That is a lot simpler. Marked as solved.
Also, you wouldn't by any chance know why this happened, right? It doesn't really matter now that I have a much simpler way of doing this, but I am still curious.

Comment: @SampathEaty Either your hex encoder is off, or your hex decoder is off. But you don't really need either one, so I wouldn't spend any more time on it.

Comment: @SampathEaty Probably a combination of things:  1. `password.getBytes()` relies on the system’s default charset, which is not the same in all operating systems.  2. `Integer.toHexString` returns a String of length 1 for byte values of 0–15.  3. `BigInteger.toByteArray` ignores leading zero bytes;  for instance, `new BigInteger("00001234", 16).toByteArray()` will return two bytes, not four.